# Azure Function Time specification

Tags: azure, event-handling, azure-functions, serverless

Can we run Azure function daily at specific two different time ? I have tried a Azure function with a specific time, but I need two times. Like 4.00 AM & 10 AM everyday.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do so by defining in CRON expression of Azure Function.

> Like 4.00 AM & 10 AM everyday

```
0 0 4,10 * * *
```

The above CRON expression({second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day-of-week}) makes use of **A set of values (, operator)**.

Please find more details on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer#ncrontab-expressions).